# What determines whether runtime_error is_nothrow_copy_constructible?

Tags: c++, exception, runtime-error

I have an implementation of an exception class that inherits from `std::runtime_error`:

```
class custom_error : public std::runtime_error {
public:
  explicit custom_error(const std::string &arg)
      : std::runtime_error(arg){};

  ~custom_error() noexcept override = default;
};
```

This implementation is, as far as possible, identical to the `libstdc++` implementation of other subclasses of `std::runtime_error`.

When running clang-tidy over this code (in some circumstances - see below), the following warning is emitted:

```
warning: thrown exception type is not nothrow copy constructible [cert-err60-cpp]
```

The relevant information about this check is [available here](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/cplusplus/ERR60-CPP.+Exception+objects+must+be+nothrow+copy+constructible).
I believe I understand the information on that page.
In particular, I believe the relevant information is that a `std::runtime_error`, and subclasses thereof, should have the trait `is_nothrow_copy_constructible`.

I have trouble reconciling the following.

#### Scenario 1:

The following code on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/rLwbqR) demonstrates that the class `is_nothrow_copy_constructible` when compiled with gcc 5.x and newer, but not when compiled with gcc 4.x.

#### Scenario 2:

On my laptop, running Ubuntu 18.04, the same class also `is_nothrow_copy_constructible` when compiled with gcc 5, gcc 7, clang 3.8, clang 5 and clang 6, all when linked against `libstdc++.so.6.0.25`.

#### Scenario 3:

On travis-ci running an instance of Ubuntu 14.04, I cannot find a single configuration in which the same class `is_nothrow_copy_constructible`.
This includes using gcc 5, gcc 6, gcc 7, clang 4 and clang 5, linked against `libstdc++.so.6.0.25`.

Here is a [specific travis build log](https://travis-ci.org/OxfordRSE/template-project-cpp/jobs/377265230) demonstrating the test failure, which uses gcc 5, linked against `libstdc++.so.6.0.25`. 
 (`custom_error` is renamed simply `Exception`.)

#### The question:

Can someone explain to me what could be determining whether the class `is_nothrow_copy_constructible`?

To me, the above demonstrates that the answer can differ when the:

- implementation
- compiler, and
- standard library version

are identical.

Comment: According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error, it may throw.

Comment: @NeilButterworth According to the linked page copying it should not throw (but constructing supplying message may throw).

Comment: As for question: gcc 4.x is old and rusty. It is not clear what exactly happens during scenario 3. Maybe it is the check method or travis configuration issue, so you should post some details (or actually a travis link)

Comment: I read [except.spec/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec#7) to mean that your ([implicitly defaulted](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#6)) copy constructor shouldn't throw unless `runtime_error`'s copy constructor can throw - maybe you could check whether you get the same results testing for `is_nothrow_copy_constructible<runtime_error>`?

Comment: @VTT I have updated the question to include a link to a travis build log with verbose compilation.

@hlt Yes - identical scenario with `std::runtime_error`.

Comment: I've noticed flag `--coverage` used. Maybe it alters compiler throw checking behavior somehow.

Comment: @VTT [just tried that](https://travis-ci.org/OxfordRSE/template-project-cpp/jobs/377475554) and the same warning from clang-tidy, so is independent of flags associated with coverage and AddressSanitizer.

Comment: The default answer to that warning is "derive from `runtime_error`", which you are already doing. It seems like that is just an implementation-dependent behavior - whenever someone else runs into this issue, the response is to [remove the check for it](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/commit/cf7786887c7ca80d86112f6b9f0aeba8cb1f2f9c)...

Comment: Also, check your Travis CI settings again - you say it runs on GCC 5, but the log says GCC 4.8, and I don't trust GCC 4.8's stdlibc++ to do the right thing with `noexcept`, it's probably too old for that

Comment: Thanks - useful to see that other people have come up against this in the wild. On the Travis point, GCC 4.8 seems to be put in as default when the language is set to `cpp`: the 'actual' compiler version is set later, and this confirmed with the CMake output as well as verbose `make` output when turned on.